# How can I add Multiple Markers on google map using json and swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift4.1

Multiple marker doesn't show on google map using swift 4.1 i am connect JSON and result show on console but how can I connect with latitude and longitude with Google maps.

```
let jsonUrl = URL(string: "http://assetlinkasia.no-ip.biz:8001/hf_tracker/api/userdevices.php?accesskey=12345&user_id=1")            
    if let url = jsonUrl {
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url)
        if let data = data {
            do{
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments)                    
                if let object = jsonObject as? [NSString: AnyObject]{
                    if let allDevices = object["data"] as? [[NSString: AnyObject]]{                            
                        print("Successfull")
                        print(allDevices)                            
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("Error Eccurred")
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my google map code here:

```
    let getLongijson = Double("67.0011")
    let getlatijson = Double("24.8607")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: getlatijson!, longitude: getLongijson!, zoom: 13.0)

    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
    self.view = mapView

   // meanView.addSubview(mapView)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: getlatijson!, longitude: getLongijson!)
    marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x:0.10, y:0.10)
    marker.title = HeadingName
    marker.snippet = Countory
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "markers")
    marker.map = mapView

    //User Location
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

   // self.menuFunction()

    mapView.delegate = self
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: how to add json with google map for multiple markers

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

**Objective-c**

```
     count = (int)locatorObject.LocationList.count; 
     for(int i=0;i< count;i++)
            {
            LocationDetails *locator = locatorObject.LocationList[i];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([locator.Lat floatValue],[locator.Long floatValue]);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            marker.title = locator.Address;
            marker.map = _googleMapView;
            }
```

**swift**

```
 for i in 0..<count {
        var locator: LocationDetails? = locatorObject.locationList[i]
        var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locator?.lat, locator?.long)
        var marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        marker.title = locator?.address
        marker.map = googleMapView
    }
```